# Mapping the other table in a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, mapping

I am working on a `C#` project querying a `Sql Db` by the auto-generated classes by the `sqlmetal` tool. That works fine.

My problem is that in my DB I have to tables (*TableA* and *TableB*) which have a `many to many` relationship, therefore, there is a third table called *TableATableB* which holds only the primary keys of *TableA* and *TableB*.

So, as expected, my EntityModel has a class named *TableA* that has a property named *TableATableB* which is a collection of all related *TableATableB* rows.

That is the auto-generated property:

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="FK_TableATableB_TableA", Storage="_TableATableB", ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="TableAId", DeleteRule="CASCADE")]
    public EntitySet<TableATableB> TableATableB
    {
        get
        {
            return this._TableATableB;
        }
        set
        {
            this._TableATableB.Assign(value);
        }
    }
```

The thing is **I would like *TableA* to have a property named *TableB* which gives me directly an `System.Data.EntitySet<TableB>` collection of all related *TableB* rows, is there a way to do that?** I have been trying to do it but I haven't found the way to map it.

Just to clarify, I know a workaround simply could be as follows, but I'm trying to see if there is a better way. Besides, this way how could I know when a *TableB* object is added to the collection in order to add the respective TableATableB object?

```
partial class TableA
{
    public List<TableB> TableB
    {
        get
        {
            List<TableB> tableBRows = new List<TableB>();

            foreach (TableATableB tAtB in this.TableATableB)
            {
                tableBRows.Add(tAtB.TableB);
            }
            return tableBRows;
        }
        set
        {
            // What to do here?
            // I need to know when an element is added in order to add its respective
            // TableATableB object
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be *LINQ-to-SQL* and not Entity Framework, isn't it? You should possibly change the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to SQL does not support the behavior you desire. L2S does not support implicit many-many collections like EF.

Entity Framework does, but requires that the all fields of the many-many table (TableATableB in your case) make up the primary key of that table.  For example, if TableA's primary key is Id and TableB's primary key is Id then TableATableB must have exactly two fields, TableA_Id and TableB_Id, that are the primary key of that table.  If TableATableB were to have three fields in this case like Id, TableA_Id and TableB_Id, and Id is the primary key of the many-many table then EF cannot and will not treat that as an implicit many-many collection.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for. I just have a little question: if `TableATableB` table has a third field, for example, a date, where would EF put that property?

Comment: I believe EF database first would generate a class named TableATableB, and that table cannot be an implicit many-many collection. Instead you'd get TableA.TableATableBs and TableB.TableATables instead of what you want (e.g. TableA.TableBs and TableB.TableAs). TableATableB would have a property that corresponds to the date field.

Comment: Aside: Have you looked at EF code first? If you are using EF, and you have complete control of the database then I recommend using [EF code first with migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) over EF database first and EF model first.